# Сворачивание и разворачивание текста в ТехтView Android

Tags: android, textview, списки

Есть список, отображающий ленту новостей в приложении Android. Текст новости может быть большим. Как его сократить до небольшого превью в несколько строчек с последней строчкой другим цветом в виде "показать полностью...", чтобы при нажатии на пункт списка или на надпись "показать полностью..."открывалось новое активити с полным текстом? Это реализуется везде и всюду, но вот как это реализуется нигде не описывается.

Если идти "в лоб", как я понимаю, то длинный текст просто сокращается в XML до нужного количества строчек с окончанием в виде "..." и добавлением нового TextView "показать полностью...", например, синего цвета, который невидим, если текст влезает и становится видимым при сокращении текста, а при нажатии на него происходит переход в новое активити с полным текстом.

Но, может, есть уже готовые более аккуратные решения, раз это используется повсеместно?

Comment: Есть множество уже [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+expandable+textview&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)/ Только все они просто разворачивают текст, а не открывают новую активити. Возможно эти библиотеки вам помогут.

Comment: Спасибо за совет